# How can I make Caps Lock work with Hebrew like it did prior to Sierra and without Ukulele?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, caps-lock

In Hebrew the Caps Lock is used to activate the vowel points. How do I restore this feature of Caps Lock in Hebrew, and without creating a new keyboard with a program that I do not know, like Ukulele?

Comment: @Tom Another Hebrew vowels question was closed as a duplicate of the question this is now closed toward. I have voted to reopen this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Apple's built-in Hebrew PC keyboard layout, you cannot make it work like before, but you should still be able to input vowels via Option plus Shift. Or you can [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znmugmn5bv44fqg/OldHebrew%20-%20PC.keylayout?dl=0) the new keyboard you need to restore the previous behavior.

Answer (score -1):

It is a regression and loss of functionality caused by Apple, plain and simple. It was not announced, much less given any justification, anywhere that I (or Google or Bing) can find.  It seems like a total goof by Apple.

Contrary to answer 1, you cannot type the same set of nikud using Option plus Shift as before with the Windows Hebrew keyboard, called "Windows - PC" on the Mac: you can type the Apple set of nikud, which is a proper subset of what you could type with Windows - PC.

For example, there is now no way to type Sin Dot and Shin Dot nikudes in the Apple set, whereas you could do so with the Windows - PC set.

Also, the placement of the keys to type with <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to get a nikud is completely different now. For example, PATAH with Windows PC was <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, but now it's <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> -- i.e., a change from 7 to 6.

So, you don't just have to change key typing from <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, you basically have to learn the entire set of nikud key locations to combine with anew.

Comment: Your post is not an answer but a combination rant/comment.  You should delete this and repost it as a comment under the question or the earlier answer, after fixing the errors:  There is no "Windows - PC" keyboard on any version of OS X, so it's not clear what you are talking about.  Plus Sin Dot and Shin Dot ARE on Apple Hebrew PC layout at  option-shift s and m.  If you don't like the different nikud locations, you can use the alternative keyboard I have provided (which takes a few seconds to generate with Ukelele).

Comment: @TomGewecke: I am afraid you were mistaken in stating, "there is no 'Windows - PC' keyboard on any version of OS X". All you or anyone needs to do to see that is to go Keyboard Preferences, click + to add a keyboard, choose Hebrew as the language, and then see that there are 3 choices: (1) Hebrew; (2) Hebrew - PC; (3) Hebrew - QWERTY. As regards the reported bug, Apple fixed this bug quite some time ago. It's not present in Mojave, nor in Catalina.